# Не работает как нужно html_entity_decode

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Вот есть такая у меня сущность html &eacute; хочу ее перекодировать в символ. Написал код на php:

```
$value = '&eacute;';

$value = html_entity_decode( $value, ENT_QUOTES, 'cp1251' );

echo $value;
```

НЕ переводит сущность html в символ. Что не так?

Comment: @czart2014, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Уберите кирилическую кодировку `cp-1251`, в ней нет такой буквы, пусть будет дефолтное  `utf-8`. [Пример](http://ideone.com/9xmGKR)

Comment: И все равно `&eacute;`.

Тут же смысл такой. На экране показывает символ, а не html `&eacute;` а в исходном коде показывает `&eacute;`. А нужно, чтоб показывало символ и на экране, и в исходном коде!

Comment: @czart2014, объясните, что именно вы хотите сделать, зачем вам отображение символа в исходном коде. Потому что если бы в исходном коде показывало букву, то смысла в кодировании этой буквы не было вообще, латиницу ведь никто же не кодирует.

Comment: Это понятно, что смысла бы не было. Но задача стоит такая, что нужно все-таки сделать, чтоб буква была в исходном коде.